# Hyperlinks not working on images

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I have uploaded my page here so that you can see clearly what I am referring to:

http://www.emmasteed.co.uk/new/

The menu section works fine it is the larger button icons at the bottom: Portfolio, Get in touch and About me.

I have hyperlinked these images as you will see in the code however nothing happens when I hover over them or try to click. What am I doing wrong? This is driving me crazy!

```
<div class="largemenubutton"><a href="portfolio.html"><img src="images/portfolio.png" alt="Portfolio" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="largemenubutton"><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/getintouch.png" alt="Contact me!" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="largemenubutton"><a href="aboutme.html"><img src="images/aboutme.png" alt="About" border="0" /></a></div>

.largemenubutton {
    width:283px;
    height:259px;
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Instead of just the link why not the code

Comment: right click - view source - it's all there :)

Comment: just remove the z-index on your class mainimage

Comment: that needs to be there because it is slightly under lapping the drop shadow.

Comment: @user3714234 - The idea is, questions should be able to help future visitors and not just you.  Once it's fixed on your site, the question serves no purpose.

Comment: @user3714234 - You should make it easy for people doing you a favour

Comment: @YannickYeboue Post that as an answer…

Comment: I understand your point about helping others so have added the code that i am referring to.

Comment: @user3714234 = I hope you have learned your lesson and can be a valuable member of this community

Comment: did you check my answer and jsfiddle?

Comment: Hello, yes I did try your answer however it did not work for me so my solution below. Thank you for you advice anyway - very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the z-index -1 there:

```
.mainimage {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

For keeping the drop shadow do the following:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
```

remove the mainhome width and apply to the container in the css:

```
.container {
  width: 850px;
}
```

Also use that container for wrapping the same way the main content for the site.

and then for the drop shadow (customize as you please):

```
.header {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px black;
}
```

This is the fiddle that represents more or less this: http://jsfiddle.net/9q7PX/

Comment: This does have the effect that I am after. I want my scrolling image to sit underneath the drop shadow? Also, why would the z-index effect the hyperlinks?

Comment: Because if you put z-index: -1 that div sits behind the parent, so it's behind it, so the mouse can not select the links. Try to inspect the links with chrome dev tools, you'll see that the main div is selected instead of the links.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions come to mind:

1) Wrap the `img` element in a `div`, and wrap that `div` with your `a` element.

2) Nix the `img` element from your DOM, and instead make it a `background-image` of a `div` (in CSS). Then wrap that `div` with your `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed to figure a way round this. I would like to thank everyone for their answers and advice as without this I probably would never have found this solution. The z-index setting on the previous div was the problem I had to get round.

Basically i created another div tag to contain my large menu buttons and placed this outside of the previous div which held my slider image which was set at z-index -1 as i wanted my image to sit behind a drop shadow above. This then allowed the links on the images to work.

Hope this makes sense and helps anyone else who has this problem.